# Ternary operators in Lua (function)

Tags: function, lua, ternary-operator

I came across this question in codewars that goes like this:

Implement a function that will run 2 different functions depending on a boolean value. Of course, it can be implemented using simple if statement. Like so:

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    if bool then return func1() else return func2() end
end
```

However, it does not pass all test cases when I want to solve it using ternary operator:

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    return bool and func1() or func2()
end
```

But this works:

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    return (bool and func1 or func2)()
end
```

I think I simply don't have enough knowledge regarding Lua. I have searched through the community about this but can't find any explicit explanation about this. I was wondering if someone could shed some light on this or just suggest some articles that might help me understand.

**UPDATE**
**EDIT**

Well, then how does the second snippet differ from the third one if `func1` always return truthy value?

Comment: Lua does not have any ternary operators! It's just that and has higher precedence than or.

Comment: see my anwer. I added some details. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    if bool then return func1() else return func2() end
end
```

The above piece of code returns func1() if bool is true and func2() else.

The following code will return `func2()` if `bool` is not true or if `bool` is true and `func1()` is not true. It will only return `func1()` if both `bool` and `func1()` are true.

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    return bool and func1() or func2()
end
```

The last piece of code will return func1() if bool is true and func2() else.

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    return (bool and func1 or func2)()
end
```

So first of all, Lua does not have any ternary operator. The clever use of and's higher precedence over or is just equivalent to ternary operators like C's ?:

Second the expression `a = b and c or d` will only work properly if c is true. This may not always be the case if you're using a function call as c.

It's a convenient way to do assignments but in many cases it increases readability and reduces mistakes to just stick to an if else statement.

Once you have to add more conditions that and or trick becomes a total mess.

So let's have another look on what is going on in the second snippet.

```
function _if(bool, func1, func2) 
    return bool and func1() or func2()
end
```

First `bool` and `func1()` will be evaluated.
If `bool` isn't true, Lua does not have to call `func1()` because the expression can never be true.
So Lua can go and evaluate `func2()` right away.
Your function will return `func2()`!

On the opposite, if `bool` is `true`, Lua will call `func1()` to see if it also `true`.
  if `func1()` returns `true`, Lua will not call `func2()`. Because of the following `or` the expression will always be `true` if `bool` and `func1()` is `true`.
  if `func1()` returns false/nil the `or` has to be evaluated. So Lua will call `func2()` as well and then return it's return value.

It is important to know operator precedence and in which cases Lua will abort evaluating expressions!

**Lua's `or` and `and` operators use short-cut evaluation. The second operand is only evaluated if necessary**

Comment: So, is there any significant difference between the second and third snippet?

Comment: yes. the third snippet will call either func1 or func2 depending on bool's value and return the respective return value. the second snippet will never return func1's return value in case it is not true. it will return func2's return value instead. and you will always call func1  in the second snippet. while the third snippet only calls only one of the functions

Comment: so in the second snippet, if bool is truthy, func1() will be called and given func1() return truthy value as well it will stop there. if bool is falsey func2() will be called, correct?

Comment: @AndyAldo yes and func2 will also be called if bool is true but func1() returns nil/false, so better stick with the third snippet or use if/else

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it will help you to see what is going on if you look at what happens when you only use `or`.

```
function func1()
    return true
end

function func2()
    return false
end

print(func1() or "default") -- true
print(func1 or "default")   -- function: 0x2377c80
print(func2() or "default") -- default
print(func2 or "default")   -- function: 0x2377cb0
```

If you use `func1` or `func2` without the parentheses, you get a function object, and function objects are always evaluated as true in Lua. (The only things evaluated as false in Lua are `false` and `nil`.)

Answer (score 0):

The `if` version is not equivalent to the second one using `and`

If func1() returns false the `or` part is evaluated and the result of func2() is returned.

The last one works (when func1 is not `nil`) because you call the function after you have determined which one to call.  So, the `bool` simply selects the 'pointer' to which function to call next.  Assuming `func1` is not `nil`, the pointers will never be false.

Comment: So, is there any significant difference between the second and third snippet?

Comment: The second calls the function func1 first to decide whether the OR will be taken based on the result of func1() being true or false.  The 3rd decides the function to use, either func1 or func2 but does not call it until after the decision is made.

Answer (score 0):

There several potential problems in your code.
1. As already mentoned if `func1` returns any `falsy` value then `func2` will be called.
2. `bool and func1() or func2()` returns exactly one result.

Comment: Can you explain to me how does the second and third one differ.

Comment: `local fn = cond and f1 or f2; return fn()` vs `local ret = cond and f1(); if not ret then ret = f2() end; return ret`